# Convergence in probability of the sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $\{\xi_t\}$ be i.i.d random variables (may not have expectation in general) and $\{z_t^{n}\}$ - i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables ($t\in \mathbb{Z}_+$) such that
$$
z_t^{n} = 
\begin{cases}
0 \ \mbox{with probability} \ (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}),\\
1  \ \mbox{with probability} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
\end{cases}
$$

$\{z_t^n\}$ and $\{\xi_t\}$ are independent of each other. So obviously random variables $z_t^{n}\xi_t$ would be $o_p(1)$.

But can we say that
$$
\frac1n \sum_{t=1}^nz_t^{n}\xi_t \stackrel{P}\rightarrow 0, \ n\to \infty?
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the $z_t^n$ independent of the $\xi_t$?

Comment: Yes, they are. Added it to the conditions. Thank you!

Comment: It is independent. But unfortunately the question is about convergence in probability, not in distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi$ denote the characteristic function of $\xi_t$.
The computation of the characteristic function $\varphi_n$ of $\frac 1n\sum_{t=1}^nz_t^n\xi_t$ gives 
$$\varphi_n(s)=\left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt n}+\frac 1{\sqrt n} \varphi(s/n)\right)^n.$$

Hence $\frac 1n\sum_{t=1}^nz_t^n\xi_t\to 0$ in distribution under some assumptions on the moments of $\xi_t$, and since the limit is constant, [in probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB1).

Actually, by a symmetrization argument, one can see that a necessary and sufficient condition for $\frac 1n\sum_{t=1}^n\xi_tz_t^n\to 0$ in probability to hold is 
$$\quad \forall s\in\Bbb R,\quad \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt n\left(\left|\varphi\left(\frac sn\right)\right|-1\right)=0.$$

Comment: I might be wrong but doesn't it converge to $0$, instead of $1$? Because of $|\varphi(t)|\leq 1.$

Comment: You are right (misprint). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: If to be honest I don't understand: characateristic function of $\sum z_t^{n}\xi_t$ tends to $0.$ Why does it mean that $\frac1n\sum_{t=1}^nz^n_t\xi_t \to 0$? If $\varphi$ converged to $1$ then it would be true

Comment: The characteristic function of $\frac 1n$ times the sum does converge pointwise to $1$ (the characteristic function of the Dirac mass at $0$).

Comment: $1-(1-1/\sqrt{n})^n$ tends to 1 as far as I understand

Comment: Yes, forget my last attempt...

Comment: Davide, I'm sorry but could you please look through the text below: the characteristic function of the sum $\sum_{t=1}^n z_t^{n}\xi_t$ is $\varphi_n(t)= (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\varphi_\xi(t))^n.$ Then the characteristic function of the $\frac1n\sum_{t=1}^n z_t^{n}\xi_t$ is $\varphi_n(t/n).$ Why does it tend to 1?

Comment: @Dan You are right, it needs a more careful analysis. I hope it's correct now.

Comment: Unfortunately the first inequality seems to be false. I'm trying to correct but no result so far.

Comment: I missed a term. It is actually more subtle than what I thought, and it seems the result you wanted does not hold in general.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9757/discussion-between-dan-and-davide-giraudo)

Comment: Please replace the asymptotics in the last sentence of the post by $\varphi_\xi(s)=1+\Omega(\sqrt{s})$.

Comment: @Did You are right, $O$ is not not enough to conclude.